# How to draw a (reasonably) thick arrow to show a ray on a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to write an accessible paper describing the least upper bound property of the real numbers, and to do that, I want to introduce the idea of rays (on a number line). For example, if I want to illustrate the set $L_r$ of numbers less than $r$ (where $r$ is some arbitrary real number).

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line=none,
            axis lines=left,
            axis line style={<->},
            xmin=-3.2,
            xmax=3.2,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            xlabel=$r$,
            xticklabel=\empty,
            xmajorticks=false,
            scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black,fill=white}, b={mark=<,draw=black}},
            restrict y to domain=0:1,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            ]
            \addplot[scatter,black,very thick] table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false]{
                0 a
                -3.2 b
            };
            \node[coordinate,label=above:{$L_r$}] at (-1.6,0.02) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following picture:

[image: attempted ray graph]

I was hoping that the bit about "mark=<" might produce a nice thick arrowhead at the left end of the number line, but no such luck! Doing that is my primary goal.

A secondary (bonus) goal is to put a little more space between the open endpoint and the label "r" that goes with it.

Just in case it needs said, I'm not looking for anything this crazy:

[image: stupidly thick arrow(head)]

Something like this is more the goal:

[image: reasonable arrow(head)]

Comment: I find it very weird to use a sledgehammer like `axis` environment for such a simple drawing like this. Is it mandatory?

Comment: Not at all! I'm simple using the tools that I've found to be (at least somewhat) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

[image: ![Number line with open interval]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in  {-4,...,4} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\draw [thin,black,stealth-stealth] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,black,-{stealth[scale=100]}] (2,0) -- (-5,0) node[fill=white,draw=black,circle, inner sep=2pt] at (2,0) {};
\draw (2,-0.5) node[anchor=north] {$r$};
\draw (-2,0.5) node[anchor=south] {$L_r$};
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

So here's a quick solution in plain Ti*k*Z.
Note that the `Circle` tip of the arrow would start just after the coordinate, hence the adjustment I made with double of the tip length.

[image: axis and solve]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0);
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,4} \draw (\i,0.1) --++ (0,-0.2) node[below] {\strut $\i$};
        \draw[Circle-Latex,line width=2pt] (2cm-4pt,0) -- (5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```